# Could not upgrade OAuth 2 token. HTTP status for remote endpoint: {$a} in moodle 4.2

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, openid, moodle

I used the custom service : OpenID for SSO. I configured the endpoints, user field mappings and rest of the things. But when I tried to login with the username and password it returns with the error mentioned above.
I have gone through the moodle documents but could not get the result.
The error is : Could not upgrade OAuth 2 token. HTTP status for remote endpoint: {$a}

I am using the Moodle Version 4.2

I tried to get the solution from  [OAuth2 Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/OAuth_2_authentication) ,
[OAuth Services](https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/OAuth_2_services), [Single Sign Off](https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Microsoft_365#Single_Sign_Off)

Trace after opening debugging mode

```
Error: mdb->get_record() found more than one record!
    line 1691 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to debugging()
    line 1651 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_record_sql()
    line 1630 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_record_select()
    line 582 of /lib/datalib.php: call to moodle_database->get_record()
    line 794 of /lib/setup.php: call to get_site()
    line 41 of /config.php: call to require_once()
    line 31 of /admin/oauth2callback.php: call to require_once()
```

Please find the screenshot of error at below link:

[error regarding oauth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrRC8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russell's answer appears to resolve the duplicate course issue - the problem shown in the trace in your question. So that part's fine and can probably be ignored now.

The screenshot (noting, you added this later), is reporting a connectivity issue, specifically, that your Moodle is blocking access to the URL. This is controlled by the [blocked hosts list setting](https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/HTTP_security#cURL_blocked_hosts_list)

Comment: Thank you @snake. Yes, it was issue related with blocked hosts. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch on debugging and copy and paste the trace into the question

Edit `config.php` and insert the following

```
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

EDIT :

Looks like you are using Moodle 4.2 ?

This line

```
line 582 of /lib/datalib.php: call to moodle_database->get_record()
```

Has this code

```
if ($course = $DB->get_record('course', array('category'=>0))) {
```

Looks like you have more than one course with a category of 0 - only the site course should be using that category

Check the course table and change the category to something else for the non-site course - the site course id is probably 1, so keep that as 0

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_course
WHERE category = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the trace in question after opening debug mode

Comment: Yes, it was 4.1 and now 4.2. Thanks.

Comment: Now, made changes in category , I got below error log<br>
More information about this error
Debug info: The URL is blocked.
Error code: oauth2upgradetokenerror
Stack trace:

Comment: Stack trace:

    line 580 of /lib/oauthlib.php: moodle_exception thrown
    line 254 of /lib/classes/oauth2/client.php: call to oauth2_client->upgrade_token()
    line 479 of /lib/oauthlib.php: call to core\oauth2\client->upgrade_token()
    line 279 of /lib/classes/oauth2/client.php: call to oauth2_client->is_logged_in()   line 624 of /lib/classes/oauth2/api.php: call to core\oauth2\client->is_logged_in()
line 163 of /admin/tool/oauth2/issuers.php: call to core\oauth2\api::connect_system_account()

Comment: Output buffer: <br /> <b>Warning</b>: Undefined array key "http_code" in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/oauthlib.php</b> on line <b>578</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: Undefined array key "http_code" in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/oauthlib.php</b> on line <b>580</b><br />

Comment: Can you please help me regarding mentioned errors?

Comment: I updated the question with the screenshot as well. Could you please review and help me to come out from this?